# How can I test if a VAST ad tag is working in JWPlayer?

Tags: jwplayer, ads, vast

I'm integrating JWPlayer with VAST so that if I can't find any ads from a primary source, I'll fallback to a second source. I was relying on onError() and onSetupError() to do this, but I'm having some issues.

Is there any way of testing for a VAST ad response and then act accordingly? Something like:

```
if (vast_response) [process ad]
else [use alternate source]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1480813-example-ad-tag-waterfalling

or:

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1665150-ad-tag-waterfalling